# Getting the velocity in Radar FMCW

Tags: signal, fft, radar

I have managed to get the frequency (the beat) frequency from an FMCW.
Here is a screen shot of a wall that's detected by the Radar.
I performed an FFT of complex I,Q data.

My questions are
1. How would I convert that peak frequency into range
2. How would I get the velocity using that frequency

Thanks

Here is the code

```
ResultI = (ResultI/256) -1;
ResultQ = (ResultQ/256) -1;

mixed1 = complex(ResultI, ResultQ);

Win=fft(mixed1,512);

plot(abs(win);
```

[image]

```
ResultQ(numel(ResultI)) = 0;

mixed1 = complex(ResultI, ResultQ);
L = 512;
Fs = 125000;
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
fft_sig = fft(mixed1, NFFT)/L;

shift = fftshift(fft_sig);
plot(abs(shift));

n=0:512;  %N=100
N=length(n);
Ts=0.000001; %period [s]
Fs= 12;  %frequency [Hz]
t=(0:Ts:Ts*n(end));
A=10;
w=0.267*pi*Fs; %oscilation frequency [rad/s]
p=1.2; %phase [rad]

[freq_response,freq_index] = freqz(shift,1,N,Fs);  %N is the number of samples
pM = max(abs(freq_response)); %magnitude
pF = freq_index(abs(freq_response)==pM); %frequency
plot(freq_index,10*log10(abs(freq_response)),'b',pF,10*log10(pM),'r*')
title(sprintf('Peak Frequency = %f Hz (%.1f dB)',pF,10*log10(pM)));
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ylabel('Power [dB]') 

f0 = 24.15e12;
lambda = physconst('LightSpeed')/f0; 
radvel = dop2speed(pks,lambda)
```

Comment: Your questions are extremely basic radar questions. You really should read a book about radar technology and/or take a course. FMCW isn't well suited to get velocity information, using a static carrier and the Doppler effect is much easier.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm using a sawtooth carrier

Comment: @AhmedSaleh based on a previous question you asked, you are using a sawtooth modulation signal not a carrier.

Comment: yes sorry, I missed typing it

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwj-65fel6HbAhWHAcAKHTzrAlIQFghPMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fwp%2Fspyy007%2Fspyy007.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2H-ulFw1WsoUG-CQLDrXSO

Comment: @Andyaka I have updated the post.. I get a velocity of 0.00005, which makes sense because its a wall.. is the process that I have done is corrected ?

Comment: Generate synthetic data to test your algorithm. As far as velocity goes, you can only get the velocity that is in the downrange axis. In other words, the velocity you measure will be how fast the target is coming toward you or moving away. Not how fast it is actually moving. If it is moving across range, its measured speed will be zero. Usually velocity is computed by looking at phase shift between multiple chirps. It is not easy or accurate to get velocity from a single chirp. You would have to unroll the phase and curve fit a quadratic to it or something.

Comment: @mkeith can you elabore the algorithm in pseudo code ?

Comment: I don't think I can explain it that easily. I worked with FM homodyne radar a bit, but it was a long time ago. You are going to need to read some books and spend some time thinking about things.

Comment: @mkeith is it simple as calculating FFT(I) then convert the doppler frequency to velocity ?

Comment: Doppler affects FMCW radar differently from a simple single frequency Doppler radar. If you mix TX and RX in a doppler radar, the frequency difference is the speed. In FMCW, when you mix TX and RX, the frequency difference is the distance of the target, not the speed. So you need to look at the frequency difference from chirp to chirp. Of course, you don't only have one target out there. There could be many targets with many different speeds. So it is not that simple.